# Android hide inflated view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have 4 views that are controlled by 1 SherlockMapActivity. Currently I am switching between views with the tabs by removeAllViews() and then re-inflate the view again. This seams like a very inefficient way of going about it.

Is there any way to just "hide" a view that has been inflated already and re-position a new view to the front? I have tried every variation of setVisibility, etc, to no avail. Here is how I am going about it right now:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //load our views!
    this.baseViewGroup = (ViewGroup)this.findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    this.mapView = new MapView(ActivityMain.this, MAP_API_KEY);
    this.mapView.setClickable(true);

    this.createMenu();
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
{
    Log.v(CLASS_NAME, "tab selected: "+tab.getPosition());

    if (0 == tab.getPosition())
    {
        this.baseViewGroup.removeAllViews();
        this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map, this.baseViewGroup);
    }
    else if (1 == tab.getPosition())
    {
        this.baseViewGroup.removeAllViews();
        this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list, this.baseViewGroup);
    }
}
```

I can then do fancy things with ViewControllers (of sorts) to restart the previous state of the view when it is re-created but this just seams crazy. Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**
I have tried saving the views (inflate once, remove but then just re-add) but I get this strange behavior. Basically, *all* inflated views are shown on top of each other, in a semi-transparent way. No amount of setVisibility() makes them totally go away.

The code I tried (added to onCreate() and onTabSelected() where appropriate):

```
//in onCreate()
this.mapLayout = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map, this.baseViewGroup);
this.moreLayout = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.more, this.baseViewGroup);

//in onTabSelected()
ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup)this.mapLayout.getParent();
content.removeAllViews();
content.addView(this.mapLayout);
```

Comment: You tried setting the visability to GONE as well?

Comment: @MikeIsreal - yes, this does nothing at all. Tried GONE and INVISIBLE but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe you need to invalidate the parent so it will redraw, otherwise gone and invisible should definitely affect the views.

Comment: Following the code in the edit that I posted, I keep getting all layouts visible or none. I have this.mapLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
this.moreLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
this.baseViewGroup.invalidate(); but this makes *all* views visible for some reason (with the strange transparency). I will try more tomorrow and post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Donot inflate views again and again. instead, have 4 class level view variables like

```
private View firstView;
private View secondView;
private View thirdView;
private View fourthView;
```

now during every tab change/press. remove all child views from parent and add, appropriate view to the parent. like,

```
parentView.removeAllViews();
parentView.addView(secondView);
```

**Edit:**

Pass null for parentView.

instead of this,

```
this.moreLayout = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.more, this.baseViewGroup);
```

do this,

```
this.moreLayout = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.more, null);
```

Comment: Sadly that just makes ViewGroup content = (ViewGroup)this.moreLayout.getParent(); return NULL so I get a null pointer exception when I removeAllViews(). :(

Comment: `content.addView(this.mapLayout);`
 you need to do this first and then you can do this operation

Comment: `this.baseViewGroup.addView(this.mapLayout);` I had to do this before i started the "ViewGroup content" stuff (before adding the views) and now it works properly! Seams a bit strange that I have to add it, remove all views, then add it again but its not as bad as having to inflate it every time.